# Slow startup on specific RAID card slot

Tags: raid, hard-drive, dell, dell-perc

i've a NX200 Dell Server with a PERC S300 raid card. 
After few problems with our old disks (readable but degraded), we changed our 4 disks :
- HE253GJ (250 Gb, 7.2 rpm, 3 gbps, before)
with
- ST500DM002 (500 gb, 7.2 rpm, 6 gbps, after)

But there is a strange problem (i'm beginner ...), the 2 slot didn't recognize the disk (no led, nothing in RAID management). I've swap all disk to isolate the problem but it persist.
I think the problem must be the slot, but ... If I insert an old disk in this slot, absolutely no problem, there is recognized and detected (but degraded, sure).

Sometimes, if i waiting 2/3 mns in raid software and if i start a rescan to find more disk, the 2 slot showing up and i can build my raid without problem ...

Do you have an idea ? Thanks !

Comment: I'd check the hardware issue first. Looks like it's a problem with connection between disk and RAID controller.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 'solved', on the PERC S300 there is 2 SAS Port, the first port connected to the backplane was broken, connected on port SAS 2 and the disk are recognized.